# How to upgrade postgresql from 9.2.0 to 9.2.4

Tags: apt, updates, postgresql

The title says it all.

if I run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` none of the postgresql packages get updated. While the psql version 9.2.0 is and the last update is 9.2.4.

Am I missing something?